# Manhwa in which the female lead and her family-in-law remember her past life

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I read this manhwa a month ago and now I can't remember the title. The family of the female lead hates her and she remembers her past life. Her family-in-law also remembers and really loves her, but her husband doesn't.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you read this?  Do you recall any names of characters or places or any significant details of how they are portrayed?  (Eye/hair/skin colour, jewelry or tattoos, odd clothing or weapons...)

Comment: Was the female lead a different person in her past life, or did she wake up in her own body in the past? Also, what colour was her hair?

Comment: Can you expand on the characters? Reincarnation stories can get confusing with the past lives. Is the husband from her past life or new life? Both? Her family hates her - how many family members does she have? Parents? Siblings? What about her in-laws, how many people there? And all of her in-laws are also reincarnated and remember their past lives, but her husband doesn't?

Comment: Likely the same answer as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269450/102326

Answer (score -1):

[Lady Isabella's Path To Happiness](https://m.tapas.io/series/lady-isabellas-path-to-happiness/info) on Tapas.io:

> For centuries, the firstborn of House Helsington has been cursed to die young, so the family produces an illegitimate child, Isabella, to take on the curse instead. To get away from her terrible home and live her last days in peace, she wants nothing more than to escape. Her chance comes when Grand Duke Noverdic asks her to marry his son, Cleor. Once she arrives in the north, she is showered with endless affection from both her in-laws and her fiancé... to the point that it's almost suspicious.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you [edit] this to explain how it matches the details provided in the question?

Comment: Is this even a regression/reincarnation manhwa?