# Regression manhwa/manga/WEBTOON where the main female lead and the in-laws have memories prior to the regression

Tags: story-identification, manga, webcomics

I read this manhwa a few months ago but I’ve been able to find it since. It’s a regression manhwa. The female lead, her mother-in-law, father-in-law and little sister-in-law all regressed back to the time before the female lead married the male lead. The female lead is very sickly and took the place of her sister in the marriage because her family hates her and she normally stays locked up. The female lead has blonde hair; the male lead and the in-laws have black hair. The male lead did not regress and does not remember the female lead like his family does.

Edit:
Female lead has a father, sister and mother.
Male lead has a father, mother and younger sister.
It’s a historic manga with nobles and what not. The male lead lives in the super cold north and after the female lead and the in-laws regress…the in-laws send a marriage proposal to the female leads house and she ends up accepting the proposal because her family thinks it’s meant for her sister.

Comment: I think we had this one asked about a month ago. The detail of the female lead being locked away by the family Sparks a memory. I think the prior question also made some comment about a ritual involving her gaining powers. Unfortunately, I don't think it was answered there either.

Comment: Is the fact that the ML's family has regressed immediately shown to the readers, or is it more of a surprise? If they all went back in time, do you have any idea what triggered this? I assume they died, but how?

Comment: It’s made apparent pretty early on that the ML’s family regressed as well. The female lead has no powers or anything of that nature. What caused the regression was the female lead dying of her sickness I believe. I’m not sure how the ML’s family regressed as the story wasn’t that far in at the time.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to find the title! *[Lady Isabella's Path to Happiness](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/8ekskxw/lady-isabella-s-path-to-happiness)* by Lee Inhye and Dulcche, official pages here: [Korean](https://page.kakao.com/content/59274036), [English](https://m.tapas.io/series/lady-isabellas-path-to-happiness/info).

[image: Title image for Lady Isabella's Path to Happiness]

> For centuries, the firstborn of House Helsington has been cursed to die young, so the family produces an illegitimate child, Isabella, to take on the curse instead. To get away from her terrible home and live her last days in peace, she wants nothing more than to escape. Her chance comes when Grand Duke Noverdic asks her to marry his son, Cleor. Once she arrives in the north, she is showered with endless affection from both her in-laws and her fiancé... to the point that it's almost suspicious.

Comment: That's great!  You could make this a better answer by including a summary, a link, a note about details you got wrong or important details you missed...

Comment: And you can accept answers by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. As a self-answer, you won't be able to accept for two days, but clicking on it will tell you how much time is left.

Comment: I went ahead and copy-pasted in a link, summary, and title page